What am I missing from this trace of the GloVe Word Embedding for DJL?
I am trying to use the GloVe word embedding for my program in DJL observe performance between CPU and GPU. However, there are no Cuda 12 jars for MxNet at this moment so I am wanting to use the PyTorch engine since it does have Cuda 12 jars. The problem with the PyTorch engine is that its model zoo does not have the GloVe word embedding so I am trying to create a torchscript file for it to read in and use. Also, I am not wanting to limit myself to one word embedding so I would rather be able to translate them using pytorch. From what I gathered from searching online is that I need to trace the model and then save it to my local file system as a torchscript file so that my DJL program can use it.
I must be doing something wrong because I am getting this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The model was not an embedding
    at ai.djl.modality.nlp.embedding.ModelZooTextEmbedding.<init>(ModelZooTextEmbedding.java:45)
    at ExampleRNN.generateTextEmbedding(ExampleRNN.java:300)
    at ExampleRNN.main(ExampleRNN.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class ai.djl.pytorch.engine.PtSymbolBlock cannot be cast to class ai.djl.nn.core.Embedding (ai.djl.pytorch.engine.PtSymbolBlock and ai.djl.nn.core.Embedding are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at ai.djl.modality.nlp.embedding.ModelZooTextEmbedding.<init>(ModelZooTextEmbedding.java:43)
    ... 2 more

I thought that tracing the word embedding and saving it would produce the correct file but that does not seem to be the case or there is something in my DJL program that is missing.
My Code for my python program is:
    model = torchtext.vocab.GloVe(name='6B', dim=50)
    model_weights = torch.load(f".vector_cache/glove.6B.50d.txt.pt")
    
    embedding_model = torch.nn.Embedding(400000, 50)
    embedding_model.weight.data = model_weights[2]
    
    traced_model = torch.jit.trace(embedding_model, torch.IntTensor([1,2,5,4]))
    torch.jit.save(traced_model, 'GloVe.6B.50d.embedding.torchscript.pt')

My Java code to load the word embedding is:
    Criteria<NDList, NDList> criteria = Criteria.builder()
    .setTypes(NDList.class, NDList.class)
    .optEngine("PyTorch")
    .optModelPath(Paths.get("/home/user01/Downloads/RNN_Files/DJLdependencies"))
    .optModelName("GloVe.6B.50d.embedding.torchscript.pt")
    .build();
    
    ZooModel<NDList, NDList> embedding = criteria.loadModel();
    
    ModelZooTextEmbedding modelZooTextEmbedding =  new ModelZooTextEmbedding(embedding);


Please use code fences format for code, errors and logs. It is hard to read the exception stacktrace as it is.

Ok, sorry. I added the code fences.

Do you actually need it as an ModelZooTextEmbedding? Like can't you just use it as a layer without information what it is? The thing is that after tracing, it doesn't necessarily know what it was before. If you really want a ModelZooTextEmbedding, try not using tracing/torch.jit and use torch.save instead if possible.

@dan1st If I use torch.save then I get a different error
Exception in thread "main" ai.djl.engine.EngineException: PytorchStreamReader failed locating file constants.pkl: file not found

@dan1st I guess I dont need ModelZooTextEmbedding. Would I just change it to SimpleTextEmbedding?

What makes you sure torch.nn.Embedding corresponds to any TextEmbedding?

@dan1st I am sure it isnt. I looked more into it and would need to make it a word embedding and not a text embedding. However, I think you are onto something about the ModelZooTextEmbedding. That might have to be changed.
